# Making TTLauncherView open animated items

Tags: ios4, three20, ttlauncherview, ttlauncheritem

I'm currently working with Three20 in an iOS project. I've got the TTLauncherView displaying with a few icons. However, I can't see to get them to open their views in an animated fashion as with the Facebook app. I've tried:

```
    [[TTNavigator navigator] openURLAction:[[TTURLAction actionWithURLPath:@"sb://launcher"] applyAnimated:YES]];
```

as well as

```
    [[TTNavigator navigator] openURLAction:[[TTURLAction actionWithURLPath:URL.absoluteString] applyTransition:UIViewAnimationTransitionCurlDown]];
```

I also can't find anything on this documentation: https://github.com/facebook/three20/blob/60340d76780ac5ab8a5dc853e3577b1c854eb6e0/src/Three20/TTNavigator.h

Any help?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

This should work. I just tried this in my code and the curl down transition works like expected. Here is the code which gets executed when the user taps an icon in the launcher:

```
- (void)launcherView:(TTLauncherView*)launcher didSelectItem:(TTLauncherItem*)item {
[[TTNavigator navigator] openURLAction:[[[TTURLAction actionWithURLPath:item.URL] applyTransition:UIViewAnimationTransitionCurlDown] applyAnimated:YES] ];
```

}

Hope this helps.